# Aggregate large pandas dataframe using multiple column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['00001C05', '00001C05', '00001C05', '00007142'],
    'mois_couverture': ['01-2018', '01-2018', '02-2018', '01-2018'],
               'categorie_A': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y'],
               'categorie_B': ['v', 'v', 'v', 'w'],
               'revenue': [40, 50, 40, 100]})


       user mois_couverture categorie_A categorie_B  revenue
0  00001C05         01-2018           x           v       40
1  00001C05         01-2018           x           v       50
2  00001C05         02-2018           x           v       40
3  00007142         01-2018           y           w      100
```

Now I would like to aggregate the column `revenue` using all the other columns as id-columns.

For this toy example here, just:

```
df.groupby(['user', 'mois_couverture', 'categorie_A', 'categorie_B'])['revenue'].sum()

user      mois_couverture  categorie_A  categorie_B
00001C05  01-2018          x            v               90
          02-2018          x            v               40
00007142  01-2018          y            w              100
```

However, in my case, this is not feasible, because the dataframe is very large and there are many many more columns such as `categorie_A` and `categorie_B`. The good news: the values in these columns usually do not change for individual user. `df.groupby` still tries to create the cartesian product of all these columns which makes it impossible to calculate.

What is the best way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this? -

```
col_list  = list(df.columns.values)
col_list.remove('revenue')
df.groupby(col_list)['revenue'].sum()
```

Comment: in principle, yes. But that also gives me: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.78 PiB trying to create some cartesian products, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the index of grouped dataframe is very large.

Just an idea: You can create *temp* column, where you compute hash of the columns you want to group on and then group on this column. For example:

```py
df["tmp"] = df[["user", "mois_couverture", "categorie_A", "categorie_B"]].apply(
    lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1
)
x = df.groupby("tmp").first()
x.update(df.groupby("tmp")["revenue"].sum())
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                          user mois_couverture categorie_A categorie_B  revenue
tmp                                                                            
-7695693783280321891  00007142         01-2018           y           w      100
-3471124568195598737  00001C05         01-2018           x           v       90
 7608015921576661100  00001C05         02-2018           x           v       40
```